# Suppose $R$ is a ring containing a field $F$ in its centre. Construct an injective ring homomorphism from $R$ to $M_n(F)$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring containing $F$ in its center. $R$ is an n-dimensional vector space over $F$, and the homomorphism is to be constructed in terms of a basis of $R$. I'm at a complete loss at what to do. We haven't even defined vector multiplication, so how can I possibly construct a ring homomorphism on a vector space?

Comment: Please make your post self-contained. People shouldn't have to read your title to understand the content of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $F\subseteq Z(R)$ you know that $x\mapsto rx$ is an $F$-linear map for each $r\in R$.

Comment: For each $x \in R$ or $r \in R$?

Comment: @chubbycantorset For each $r\in R$.

Comment: But don't we want to define a function from $R$? So wouldn't we want a definition sending everything in $R$ (which, in your post, would be $x$) to something?

Comment: @chubbycantorset Think about the function $m_r:R\to R$ defined by $m_r(x)=rx$. This is $F$-linear because $F\subseteq Z(R)$, and thus, choosing a basis, we can association to $m_r$ a matrix in $\text{Mat}_n(F)$. Think now about the association $r\mapsto m_r$.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying, but I still don't quite understand what it means. I'm trying to see how this would work in the case of, say $F = \mathbb{R}$, and $R = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Here you can embed $\mathbb{C}$ into $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$ as $a+bi\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}a& -b\\ b & a\end{pmatrix}$. Now, I skipped a step--I found a linear transformation consisting of $a+bi$, and then took its matrix WRT to the basis $(1,i)$. What linear transformation was this?